# How to get specific data using inner join in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am stuck while implement inner join in codeigniter. it works fine without where condition. but when i use where condition it return empty result.
Please Help me to find out the problem.

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('user');
 $this->db->join('issue', 'user.id = issue.uid', 'inner');
 $this->db->where('issue.uid', $id);
 $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
 return $query;
```

Here is the final query

```
 SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` INNER JOIN `tbl_issue` ON `tbl_user`.`id` = 
`tbl_issue`.`uid` WHERE `tbl_issue`.`uid` = '2'
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: have you checked, you have a matching record with uid in your db?

Comment: Get the Raw query using following function $this->db->last_query() and compare to see if this is the query you want or something else.

Comment: yes @UzairKhan if i run query without where condition it return all records match in both table, but i need only one

Comment: get a raw query as mentioned by @user1309690 to check if your query having the $id received or not

Comment: No it return empty result

Comment: SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` INNER JOIN `tbl_issue` ON `tbl_user`.`id` = 
`tbl_issue`.`uid` WHERE `tbl_issue`.`uid` = '2' run this query in your phpmyadmin to check if you have any issue or you have a matching record.

Comment: what is your actual table name, is it `tbl_user`&`tbl_issue` or `user`&`issue`? and also what is the actual `$this->db->last_query()` result?

Comment: @HastaDhana i use prefix that automatically add 'tbl_' . Actual table name is tbl_user & tbl_issue

Comment: Have you tried running that query from mysql admin tool like phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

In My Model ::

```
public function innerjoindata($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('issue', 'user.id = issue.uid', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('issue.uid', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```

RESULT ARRAY :::

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => demouser
            [hobby] => reading
            [uid] => 1
            [gym] => yes
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [username] => demouser
        [hobby] => reading
        [uid] => 1
        [gym] => no
    )
```

)

Your Query is 100% Write I think Your Database Has No Relevant Data That's Why Create Problem
Hope You it's help YOU

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence!

Comment: your SQL query is 100% right 
please check your database manually and see your accepted data there or not

Answer (score 0):

As per the given code, you are providing the correct query. Please try to get directly from the second table with where condition.

SELECT * FROM `tbl_issue` WHERE `tbl_issue`.`uid` = '2'.